# Downloaded image doesn't show in gallery

Tags: android, image, download, save

In my application when i download an image ,it downloads but doesn't show in gallery image whats the problem?
i tried to use mediaScanner but it doesn't work for me.
thanks.

```
            Storage sss = SimpleStorage.getExternalStorage();

            String path = "myApp" + "/" +"qaiqai21";

            sss.createDirectory(path);
            try {

                lastFileName  = "test" + "_TESTINT_" + 
                randomString(3) + ".jpg";
                sss.createFile(path,  lastFileName, 
                IOUtil.readFile(response));

              } catch (IOException e) {
            }

                dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);              

        }
    });
```

Comment: to which directory location you downloaded the image ? post your image downloading code.

Comment: you should notify the device about new media file for it to understand you have a new image there.

Comment: After downloaded image refresh  gallery.

Comment: i've added the download code , how can i scan or notify device about the new media? @VladMatvienko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call below code after successful download

```
/**
 * Add captured image to the gallery
 *
 * @param context,uri
 */
public static void addToGallery(Context context, Uri uri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(uri);
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to know if you device api >=23 or not , if yes so give it write/read external storage in run time ,
step two  in code that download file in `OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(dataDirPath);`  dataDirPath must be the gallery directory `dataDirPath= context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);`

so if your file not in **Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES**  it will not save in gallery

Comment: Sorry. You talk nonsense.

Comment: how it is nonsense ?? 
every word in my answer i mean it

Comment: he can't download any file in devices >23 if he don't set the permission in runtime , so on i told him he can download file to gallery but just need to set file path to Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES , and there is  a lot of resources in internet